# Is there any way to select a region of image as wallpaper on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gnome, desktop-background, gnome-tweaks

The image that I want to set as wallpaper gets cropped from undesirable centre location, no matter which option I select in the gnome tweaks. I have tried all "centre", "scaled", "spanned", etc. options. I want to select specific region of image as my wallpaper.

Is there an android like feature where I can drag a box and select that region of image as my wallpaper? Is there any software that does this?

I can crop the image using imagemagick, but I was looking for an easier tool to do the job.

PS - I am running I single screen setup.

Comment: Because, I am thinking in term of android wallpaper tool which give you the most accurate info about how the wallpaper will look like once set with the box. That compared to imagemagik cropping, seems tedious, with setting the start co ordinates and the manual setting of images region of intereset x length and y length. I was looking at this https://codeyarns.com/tech/2014-11-15-how-to-crop-image-using-imagemagick.html#gsc.tab=0, and https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/XYCoordinatesUsingIm#:~:text=Alternatively%2C%20press%20R%20in%20the,left%20corner%20of%20the%20window.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Select a Region of an Image as Wallpaper**

- Modify the image how you want it using LibreOffice Draw. See: https://www.libreofficehelp.com/crop-image-libreoffice-draw/
- Save it as a .png file.
- Right click the screen and select "Change Background".
- Select "Add Picture" and then select your image.
- Adjust height to width ratio if necessary.

Comment: How would you select resize with lower region of the image, or the upper region using this tool? I think this is what you are talking about? https://itsfoss.com/resize-images-with-right-click/

Comment: @NiharGht: I use LibreOffice Draw myself because it comes with Ubuntu and I don't need to download anything. I have added a link to the above answer.